# Choosing best discrete classifier in ROC analysis

Tags: roc, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to do ROC analysis on my dataset.

Namely, I'm trying to find the optimal set of parameters for a predictive model. Given I just use discrete classifiers, all I have are points in the ROC space.

reading "An Introduction to ROC Analysis" by Fawcett (2006) tells that

> "Informally, one point in ROC space is better than another if it is to
>   the northwest (tp rate is higher, fp rate is lower, or both) of the
>   first classifier."

So I guess my question is how to make the process "formal" with a sound methodology that I can back up with proper literature.

[The wikipedia example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ROC_space.png#/media/File:ROC_space.png) makes it really obvious that given those 5 points, C' would be the best classifier. but that is done visually, and i would like automate the process.

Other questions based on my searches here on the stackexchange usually deal with the scoring-type classifiers (as pointed out again in Fawcett, 2006) and so I feel is not relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Off of my pragmatic (and non-academic) thinking, I thought of:

1. using the shortest distance to the point `(0,1)`,
2. using the slope of the line connecting the classifier to again the point `(0,1)` and using the steepest slope, supposedly to maximize TPR and minimize FPR.

but again I cannot find any literature to back these ideas.

My ROC plot by the way, looks like this:[image: ROC plot]

Comment: You really want a cost function...

Comment: @Calimo it would seem so, stumbled upon `What ROC Curves Can’t Do (and Cost Curves Can)` by Drummond and Holte. are there any resources that can serve as some sort of crash-course into Cost Fxns?

Comment: Btw your plot doesn't look like a ROC curve, which is normally a line going from (0,0) to (1,1), increasing in a montone way.

Comment: @Calimo i just plotted the results of each confusion matrix generated per simulation. isn't that to be expected from something that has a discrete classifier? from what i understand, my plot is just like the plot on wikipedia's example, only i have way more points.

Comment: Ok, but then that's not a ROC curve, which shows the operating performance of *one* classifier as the *decision threshold* varies (and not the model parameters). Beware of standard ROC curve analysis tools here that may just not be tailored for your problem.

Comment: @Calimo yes i understand. but therein lies my question, i can't seem to find a method that would choose a classifier (if at all possible) from this kind of plot. fawcett touches on this on his "informal" description, but i was hoping there's a solid, automate-able way to do this.